# Nginx multiple backend one server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a server without domain name: 10.23.33.251. On this server I have two backends (spring boot):
10.23.33.251:8888/apis/a/lot/of/apis
10.23.33.251:9999/apis/a/lot/of/apis

Now I want to configure nginx to handle any request that:

`/be1/employees/1?very_long_params`
will be proxy_pass (or proxy_redirect) to `10.23.33.251:8888/apis/employees/1?very_long_params`

`/be2/products/10/very/long/params`
will be proxy_pass (or proxy_redirect) to `10.23.33.251:9999/apis/products/10/very/long/params`

But I could not make it work.
Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8443;
    server_name localhost;

    location /be1/* {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8888/apis;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }

    location /be2/* {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:9999/apis;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to access localhost:port/apis/products/... without /be1 or /be2 since my spring boot projects does not have these paths. But if required I can adapt spring boot to add these paths to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location`s are defined wrong. You’re trying to use a regular expression but are missing the `~` (or `~*`) operator for that.

It is however not necessary to use regular expressions, you could just use prefix locations:

```
…
location /be1/ {
    …
}

location /be2/ {
    …
}
```

See also: [Location Directive Documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it doesn't work. Seems that ngonx append /be1, /be2 to the proxy_pass but I don't want that